# Jquery Datepicker (show full date)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this datepicker working with an input text :

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  firstDay: 1,
  altField: "#datepicker",
  closeText: 'Fermer',
  prevText: 'Précédent',
  nextText: 'Suivant',
  currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
  monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
  monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
  dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
  dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
  weekHeader: 'Sem.',
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',});

});
```

when an user set a numeric day in the input ,I want the program shows the day written and current month + year (full date in format dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: what output exactly want?

Comment: Hi Deena, output I need in the input text is the full date : if an user writes 12, it appears 12 / 06 / 2015

Comment: yes please, if posssible

Answer (score 0):

Try add this: `format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'`

Comment: not answer to my question I just need month and year set automaticaly when an user set a day